# Why doesn't my PHP handle a simple form submission?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been working on a register page for my website.

Below is the HTML code & form for the register.

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <td valign='top'>
                <input type='text' name='Username' id='Username' placeholder='Enter your username.'>
            </td>
            <td valign='top'>
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' id='SubmitRegister' value=''>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <font style='font-size:13px;color:#aaa;'>3-20 alphanumeric characters - no spaces</font>
</form>
```

And below is the PHP (on same page) to define the variables, thus proceeding with the registration.

```
$Username = secure($_POST['Username']);
$Submit = secure($_POST['Submit']);
```

However, upon clicking my Submit button, nothing happens. I have it doing this upon $Submit -

```
if ($Submit) {
    echo "Test";
}
```

I have figured out one problem with that using the function secure() below blocked it from working because mysql_real_escape_string() needed a valid database connection (which was fixed.)

Here is the function.

```
function secure($value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($value)));
    return $value;
}
```

I'm probably just overlooking a simple error, but this is irritating me and has been holding me back for days. Thanks in advanced. :)

Comment: The first error is to use mysql_* functions, as they're deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: why do you need to 'filter' submit?

Comment: Your `secure` function is nonsense. Apply _context-appropriate_ escaping measures to values at the moment you _bring_ them into that context.

Comment: If your purpose is to save these strings into a MySQL database, just use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and use `htmlentities()` when you render them out from the database.

Answer (score 4):

You need an actual value for the `value` attribute on your submit button or you could do `isset($Submit)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have simple mistake there in the form. Your submit button value is empty and you are using it in your code. This always returns `false` for your if condition.

Change:

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit' id='SubmitRegister' value=''>
```

To:

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit' id='SubmitRegister' value='Submit'>
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks dude, that fixed it perfectly. Never would've seen that.

Comment: Never forget to tick the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The value of your submit button is '' because you say `value=''`. This is the value you read here: `$Submit = secure($_POST['Submit']);`

It is an empty string. And empty string evaluate to false. So the check `if ($Submit)` returns false, and doesn't execute.

Usually the value of the submit button is not used. And checking is usually done by just checking if for example the username was given.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['Username'] ) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

rather than

```
if ($Submit)
```